# javascript function with activerecord input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Ruby on Rails app. After `users/home` is rendered, it sends an ajax call to `users#feed`. The action `feed` performs a query and sends a list of users to `feed.js.erb` in which I can mix javascript and erb to render the users on the page. However, to make the code neat, I'd like to create a javascript function that takes the database object (list of users) as input and renders them on the page. This way I can use this function in other pages, too. What is the best way to do that? Is it possible to convert the activerecord database object to some javascript object that I can easily work with (do things similar to users[0].name, users[2].address, etc)? One way would be to convert to json or string, but I can get the information (such as users[0].name) easily out of the string.

Here is part of the code in `feed.js.erb`:

```
function showUsers() {
  <% if @users.empty? %>
    alert("no change");
  <% else %>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      $("#<%= j user.id %>").html("<%= j user.name %>");
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
}
showUsers();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can call JSON.parse() upon @users.to_json

ex: `showUsers(JSON.parse(<%= @users.to_json %>))`

But you can also return the information as json, instead of js.erb. So you would have this function on the client side and would pass the users object to your function on the AJAX callback.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. So if I use JSON.parse() and define `def function showUsers(u) {...}` do I access the first user's name with `u[0].name` in the function?

Comment: I'm confused... `def function`? I thought you were wanting to use it on javascript...

Comment: Sorry, typo. I meant I define a function in javascript like `function showUsers(u) {...}`, and then call it will `showUsers(JSON.parse(<%= @users.to_json %>))`. My question is what is the correct syntax for accessing different users while defining the javascript function? Is it like `u[0].name` for accessing first user's name?

Comment: Yes, the syntax is right.

Simple test on the console:
var users = [{name: 'Foo'}, {name: 'Bar'}];
users[0].name
"Foo"